# Should I display chosen pieces of a view by hiding/showing with div or using partial views?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am creating an MVC3 web app. It has a series of cascading dropdowns and related buttons. Depending on what the dropdowns are set to and which buttons the user presses, many different things can be displayed. So far in my view I have added each of these possibilities in a div tag and then using javascript I have hidden or shown them as needed. This has created one giant view that is kind of unmanageble.
Lately I have come across partial views in my research. I think I might be able to just save each of the possibilities that can be shown into partial views and then just have a particular partial view be shown based on the button presses. However, from research, this doesn't seem to be what partial views are meant for.

Should I keep using divs that I hide/show as needed, or are partial views a better choice, or is there a better solution that I haven't thought of/found?

Comment: Just a piece of advice: I use a lot Asp.net MVC, but when I have a situation like this (when the user interface change a lot and have different inputs and scenarios) I add to my solution Knockout.js -> http://learn.knockoutjs.com/, is very very useful for things like this.

Comment: Partial views could work fine. In you events, use AJAX to call a controller method that return the partial view and include the result in your html, although if you have _"one giant view that is kind of unmanageble"_ perhaps you should be considering a different approach such as a multi-step wizard